# Link root directory to home folder for user

Tags: linux, command-line

Is it possible to link the root directory `/` to the user's home directory `$HOME` in Linux? I want to restrict the user's access to the system, the long way would be to wrap each gnu core util in an argument parser and change all the absolute paths to `$HOME/...` instead of `/...` but that would be painful. There has to be an easier, and more universal way... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is in the `chroot(2)` system call.  You can designate the user's login shell as a utility that does the appropriate `chroot(2)` for that user and execs a shell. The filesystem visible to the user would be what was setup in the `chroot(2)`.